# Missing method PasswordDeriveBytes (PBKDF1) in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, aes, .net-core

I'm developing a service in .NET Core 1.1. It connects to a legacy database which stores data encrypted with AES Rjindael. The decryption algorithm uses System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes() method to create the IV.

It looks like this function was not ported to .NET Core because it is obsolete. Unfortunately, I don't have the option of replacing the legacy data and code to use a better algorithm. Somehow, I need to get an implementation of this algorithm to make it backward compatible.

Any suggestions on how to to implement these algorithms? Thanks!

*Update*

Accepting Maarten Bodewes's answer to copy the mono source code, although it wasn't feasible for me to implement. The problem is that you would have to port a big chunk of mono crypto to get it working. (I found a way to avoid using PasswordDeriveBytes). Thanks Maarten!

Comment: FWIW PasswordDeriveBytes will be coming back in netstandard2.0, so for now you can use a polyfill, then use the framework's when it's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the code from Mono, it should be OK *as long as you do not require more bytes from PBKDF1 as the output of the hash function*.

Don't forget to read up on the Open Source licensing.

Comment: Or from .NET Core: http://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Csp/System/Security/Cryptography/PasswordDeriveBytes.cs,0b54c5106dead015

Comment: Good suggestion, but it looks like I have to re-implement the much of the Mono Cryptography system. The PasswordDeriveBytes makes use of many other  library functions. (I'm guessing they left it out of .NET core because it isn't an easy port.)

Comment: The implementation of `PasswordDeriveBytes` is broken beyond belief if you go over the amount of output provided by the hash. That's even a no-fix from the Mono guys (!). Furthermore, PBKDF1, the algorithm that it implements, has been surpassed by PBKDF2 (RFC2898DeriveBytes) so it's use has been deprecated. Enough reasons to leave it out of a core library.

Answer (score 0):

PasswordDeriveBytes is obsolete, use Rfc2898DeriveBytes instead

```
var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password,
            new byte[] {0x49, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55,
            0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x60, 0x61});
```

But this won't help you when your data have been already encrypted by the obsolete function and you need to decrypt them.